# Stytch social login fails to authenticate

Tags: authentication, oauth, stytch

Stytch fails to authenticate when passing custom TTL for session.

```
{
"error_message" : "The state in the cookie doesn't match with the state in the query parameter. Please reach out to the application developer for support.",
"error_type": "oauth_state_mismatch",
"error_url": "https://stytch.com/docs/api/errors/400/oauth_state_mismatch"
}
```

```
const customMinutes = 60;
await authenticator.authenticate(token, {
   session_duration_minutes: customMinutes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Stytch uses typescript and hence you need to convert the const string to Number.

```
const customMinutes = 60;
await authenticator.authenticate(token, {
  session_duration_minutes: Number(customMinutes)
});
```